# Uncountable subsets of the unit interval

Tags: measure-theory

Is every uncountable subset of $[0,1]$ homeomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]$ that has a given positive Lebesgue measure $\epsilon$ where $0<{\epsilon}<1$? This assertion holds for intervals (which can be rescaled), and for Cantor sets, but does it hold in general? I apologize if the question is a little vague. I cannot seem to work out how to classify the uncountable subsets of the unit interval.

Comment: What if the given subset is not measurable?

Comment: It's consistent with the usual axioms of set theory (ZFC) that the cardinality of the continuum is $\aleph_2$ and all subsets of cardinality $\aleph_1$ have Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: Hagen's comment is prompting me to ask whether a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ is always homeomorphic to a measurable subset in the same interval.

Comment: Andreas, I apologize. I don't know much set theory. I understand that ${\aleph}_{0}$ is used to denote countable sets.  What do you mean by ${\aleph}_{1}$ and ${\aleph}_{2}$? Please forgive my ignorance.